# Установка кук на страницу

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, устанавливаю куку таким образом

```
setcookie ("viewid", $_GET["id"]);
```

она добавляется в браузере, но вызывать её я могу только на той странице где её установил, я зашел в оперу, открыл куку в настройках, Перед именем кукиса viewid вписалось надпись item, Это название моей странички, вопрос, как сделать что бы весь сайт видел эту куку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по документации: [setcookie](https://www.php.net/setcookie)

```
$time = 0; // до перезагрузки броузера
setcookie("viewid", $_GET["id"], $time, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, нужно установить время действия куки, иначе они удаляются автоматически после закрытия браузера.